# Best way to extract metadata in Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So my objective is to feed thousands of emails into an Amazon S3 bucket and what I would like to do is to be able to extract certain metadata from these emails(which contain attachments). I would like to extract data such as the Sender's email, the Date of email arrival, the Email content and the attachment file name ad extension.

How would I be able to do this using Amazon S3's object metadata property? Could anyone advise as to what key-value pairs I would use here?

EDIT: I originally mentioned 'bucket's metadata property' but I realize I meant to say 'object's metadata property'. How would I pull this data using the metadata/tags bucket option?

Comment: So what is your question? How to extract metadata from am email? (protocol?  programming language?) Or how to store metadata on an S3 object? I mean - S3 will  not *pull* any metadata. You need to read the metadata from email messages and store them along the content. So - please try to focus your question

Comment: I apologize for not narrowing the question down, im a bit unsure of the process of the data extraction here o its somewhat confusing to me in itself. I will be using Zapier(middle man service to extract data based on an incoming Gmail mail with an attachment) to pull its data, and store that in an Amazon S3 bucket. But i'm wondering how I would be able to single out certain metadata(like the details I mentioned in my original post) based on that procedure. My process would be as follows: Set up a Zap that triggers off a new incoming mail, send that data to an S3 buckets, pull metadata.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it no longer applies to your use case. Just remember that if you are able to do so, the best way is to extract the metadata and then upload the files creating tags with such metadata. However, using Zapier, I don't know whether that's possible.

Comment: Would Zapier coupled with AWS Lambda be a more viable approach given what my end goal is, which would be to read various email format attachments(PDF, CSV files, etc) that come in by Gmail, and parse their analytical data?